# Git tag message template?

Tags: git, templates, tags, config

Is there a way to setup a `git tag` message template similar to the way the commit message template works?

With `git config` we could configure a template for commits, pointing to some `.git-msg-template`. This would, for example in `~/.gitconfig`, look like this:

```
[commit]
  template = ~/.git-msg-template
```

However, if you read through the git documentation or simply lookup the `git config tag.*` options in terminal, there seems to be no `git config tag.template`, only `git config commit.template` setting.

Nevertheless, even without setting up a custom `commit.template`, the default message for commits and tags differs for me. Commits start with `Please enter the commit message ...`, add branch information and so on while tags simply have `Write a message for tag: v1.0.0`. Thus, internally, there should be different templates for commits and tags?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no template file option for `git tag`; the template is [hard coded into the Git source](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9bc233ae1cf19a49e51842c7959d80a675dbd1c0/builtin/tag.c#L134-L141).  There is, however, a `-F` argument that reads the message from a file.  Note that `git tag -m` or `git tag -F` will skip running the editor unless you also add `--edit`.  You could therefore get the effect you want using:

```
git tag --edit -F ~/.git-tag-template
```

(I suspect a patch that adds a template-file configuration to `git tag`, with the code similar to that in `builtin/commit.c`, would be welcome.)